# Can someone explain how to use Ward's method to initialize k-means?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I understand HAC (hierarchical agglomerative clustering) using Ward's method as the proximity measure. But once I do that, how do I use it to initialize k-means? Do I just grab the k clusters at a pre-determined k that I'd already planned to use for k-means? Or does the hierarchical clustering help me to choose k as well?

Comment: Have you seen this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13817/how-does-ward-clustering-in-rs-hclust-function-work) and this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/Cluster_Analysis.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this to help you choose k, obviously.

But I don't really see the point of doing k-means when you already did HAC. The main reason to do k-means is because it is usually fast, and HAC is always slow. So that seems to be overkill to me.

Comment: i was thinking same way. K-means is `O(N*K*I)` where _K_ is number of clusters and _I_  is number of iterations before deciding "enough" .. whereas _HAC_ is cubic afaik (are there more efficient versions of _hac_ ?)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350/lectures/08/lecture-08.pdf it makes quite sense: the technique consists in determining k with Ward's and then apply k-means "starting from the clusters found by Ward's method to reduce the sum of squares from a good starting point".